# Why are my querystring parameters being doubled up in the post body of my ASP.NET MVC 4 Application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http, asp.net-mvc-4, http-post

Here are the relevant bits of my

Viewmodel:

```
    [Display(Name = "One Per Line")]
    public bool OnePerLine { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Comma Separated")]
    public bool CommaSeparated { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Upper Case")]
    public bool UpperCase { get; set; }
```

View:

```
                    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
                {
                    .

                    .
                    <div class="control-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.OnePerLine, "One Per Line?", new Dictionary<string, object> { { "class", "control-label" } })
                        <div class="controls">
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.OnePerLine)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CommaSeparated, "Comma separate them?", new Dictionary<string, object> { { "class", "control-label" } })
                        <div class="controls">
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.CommaSeparated)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UpperCase, "Uppercase?", new Dictionary<string, object> { { "class", "control-label" } })
                        <div class="controls">
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.UpperCase)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    .
                    .
                }
```

And here's what I see in fiddler during the post:

```
OnePerLine=true&OnePerLine=false&CommaSeparated=true&CommaSeparated=false&UpperCase=true&UpperCase=false
```

When this gets to my controller the viewmodel has the correct values from the view, I just find the doubling up odd in the post body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dug around some more and found the answer [here.](http://forums.asp.net/t/1425806.aspx)

Turns out the Html.Checkbox helper renders an addition hidden input to address scenarios where unchecked checkboxes are not sent in the request.